# Unable to Handle MISRA error 13.2 using a volatile pointer

Tags: c, volatile, misra

I am not sure how to fix the fallowing MISRA error 13.2, The value of an expression and its persistent side effects shall be the same under all permitted evaluation orders. I know the error is flag because buf is a volatile pointer. But I have no choice to declare it has volatile since his location in ram can change.
I got the fallowing code

```
volatile uint32_t * volatile buf;

void function1()
{
 uint32_t TmpSize; 
 TmpSize = buf[0u];

 /*do something with TmpSize here*/
}
```

Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Why is both the pointer and its target volatile?

Comment: Because the data might change and the location of the buffer might also change. The address of this buffer is send from core1 to core2 during run time. It is use to share data in between the 2 cores of my mcu.

Comment: You could split the expression statement in two so there is a sequence point. `volatile uint32_t *bf = buf;` `TmpSize = bf[0u];`. You may need some way to synchronize changes with whatever is modifying `buf` and `buf[x]` if the old `buf[x]` becomes stale when `buf` is changed.

Comment: @IanAbbott: `uint32_t *bf = buf;` gets the value of `buf`. Getting the value of `buf` is already sequenced before using it to fetch `buf[0u]` by C 2018 6.5 1: “… The value computations of the operands of an operator are sequenced before the value computation of the result of the operator.” That is, since `buf` is an operand of `buf[0u]`, its value computation is sequenced before computing the subscript operation.

Comment: thank you for the reply @IanAbbott. Your solution remove the error 13.2 but is replace by MISRA C 2012 rule 11.8 violation: [R] A cast shall not remove any const or volatile qualification from the type pointed to by a pointer.
I did the fallowing 
`uint32_t * pTmpBuffer = buf;`
`TmpSize = pTmpBuffer[0u];`

Comment: @Jee It looks like you saw my `uint32_t *bf = buf;` before I edited my comment to read `volatile uint32_t *bf = buf;`.

Comment: @IanAbbott, Yes sorry for this. This solution is working !! thank you very much!

Comment: @Jee I wouldn't say it's a very good solution, but I'm glad it worked for you. If your system implements proper synchronization functions then you should use those instead of misusing `volatile`.

Comment: @IanAbbott, Can you tell me more about the proper way of doing this? I am curious and want to write good software. What do you mean by proper synchronization function? and by misusing the volatile keyword?

Comment: I am afraid the construct `anything * volatile buf` is not a great idea. This means to me, that the buffer may switch unexpectedly to a new location. What is about the old buffer, do you `free()` it immediately after switching over? Then your sample function may grab data from that freed area.

Comment: @user5329483 thank you for your reply. these are legitimate concern. I will address them!

Comment: @Jee *The address of this buffer is send from core1 to core2 during run time*  You really need to provide a lot more details on your system.  Compiler, hardware, OS (if applicable).  Because `volatile` will not make accesses to the pointer *atomic*.  If your hardware doesn't update whatever a pointer is on your system atomically, you're creating the possibility of reading a pointer value that's neither the old value or the new one - perhaps the high-order bits of the old one and the low-order bits of the new one.  Or the reverse.  Or any other combination.  So please add more details.

Comment: (cont)  If that ever happens, you will probably never be able to recreate the bug.  And if it happens often enough, you will really have problems.  And the moment you put your process under a debugger, you'll change the timing and the bug will likely disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Unspecified order of evaluation is only a problem in expressions where it matters. As the rule says, "the value should be the same under all permitted evaluation orders". The evaluation of `TmpSize` (before assignment) and the evaluation of `buf` aren't sequenced in relation to each other but it should not matter in this case.

Other MISRA rules enforce the use of `volatile` qualified variables not to get mixed with other unrelated operands. Your use here is therefore correct - copy the variable into a local temporary one and do other forms of arithmetic etc on that local copy from there.

Now of course the `* volatile` qualifier on the pointer makes things further complex - you might have to get rid of that one first through a separate assignment

Also keep in mind that `TmpSize = buf[0u];` is equivalent to `TmpSize = *(buf+0u);`. This might be what the tool is upset about. You could simply try to change the code to `TmpSize = *buf;` and see if that changes anything.

```
volatile uint32_t* tmp_ptr = buf;
uint32_t tmp_size = *tmp_ptr;
```